# VBA adding cell validation failing for single cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro which gets data from another sheet as a Range object and uses that Range object to add a validation on a cell on the current sheet like this

```
With Cells(c.Row, colResource).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & Sheets(sheetResources).Name & "!" & resRng.Address
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

This works fine except when `resRng` object has only one cell.
What can cause a range with multiple cells to work but a single cell range to fail?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this shows how bizarre Excel can be.

Firstly, look at what is being fed into the `formula1` parameter.

If a single cell is selected:

```
$G$2
```

If a range of cells is selected:

```
$G$2:$G$3
```

Infuriatingly, Excel is expecting a start and an end to your range.

The solution is to check the range size, here is an example piece of code based on yours that I used for testing that you can adjust to your needs.

```
Sub add_validation()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection


With Cells(1, 1).Validation
    .Delete
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & rng.Address & ":" & rng.Address
    ElseIf Selection.Count > 1 Then
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & rng.Address
    End If
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With

End Sub
```

And your code with the size check implemented:

```
With Cells(c.Row, colResource).Validation
    .Delete
    If resrng.Count = 1 Then
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & Sheets(sheetResources).Name & "!" & resrng.Address & ":" & resrng.Address
    ElseIf resrng.Count > 1 Then
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & Sheets(sheetResources).Name & "!" & resrng.Address
    End If
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

Comment: That was a mind-numbingly simple solution to a frustrating problem. Yes excel is bizarre! In a ideal object-oriented world, Excel should just be calling a function inside the Range object and asking it for the right address and the Range object should handle the single cell on its own. But its not an ideal world after all.
Thanks a million Zerk. I wish I could upvote your answer a thousand times but I don't have enough reputation to do so!

Comment: @ArijitKanrar I mean, you could upvote it _once_. You could also have accepted it.